# How to count the number of occurences in different specific cells from a sheet 1 to another sheet 2?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In `sheet 1`, in cells `G26`, `G45`, `G65`, `G85`, I have the word "ok". In `sheet 2`, in cell `A1`, I want to count the number of occurrences of the word "ok" from the specified cells in `sheet 1`. Somehow, using `countif` or `SUM(countifs)` returns that this is not a function or #value? in the `A1` cell in sheet 2.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

used:

```
SUM(COUNTIFS(SHEET1!G26:G45:G65:G85,"OK")
```

and

```
COUNTIF(SHEET1!G26:G45:G65:G85, "OK)
```

None of these two work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COUNTIF` will only accept a single range.

Try:

```
=COUNTIF(SHEET1!G26:G85, "OK")
```

or:

```
=COUNTIF(SHEET1!G26:G45, "OK") + COUNTIF(SHEET1!G65:G85, "OK")
```

If you really must not count the cells in `G46:G64`

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
=CountIF(SHEET1!G26:G85;"OK")
```

(Mind the semicolon instead of the comma)

For your information: G26:G85 means "take all the cells from G26 to G85", it does not mean "take G26 and G85", hence I didn't put the other cells, as they are in the range from G26 to G85.